# Windows 7 has blocked a website IP address

Tags: windows, ftp, ip, firewall, ping

I think my Windows 7 has blocked an website IP address, It was working fine few hours ago and i was able to access the website and was able to move files using FTP then suddenly FTP stopped connecting to the host ip i entered. I checked the ip address by pinging and the result was 100% loss. I tried to access the website and it was not opening. In the mean while my client checked the website in US and it was working fine over there but i had no access. Can you please guide me what's wrong?

Comment: Are you pinging the IP or the domain name? Could be a DNS issue on your computer

Comment: I was pinging through IP. I also tried ipconfig /flushdns but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution of my problem by editing host file and enter the IP address for the website, then go to command prompt and enter the following command ipconfig /flushdns . This will resolve the problem if you'll have any time.